# .htaccess Multiple Rewrite Rule overwriting issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

First all i'm not an expert of .htaccess and Rewrite Rules.

I have some Rewrite rules and all of them are working.
When i added new rules; it's overwriting other rules and redirecting wrong page

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ article-list.php?link=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ article-list.php?link=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^videolar/$ video-list.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

When i try to hit url `www.mywebpage.com/videolar/1`

Unfourtunately it's redirecting to `article-list.php` page.

Is there any way to resolve the issue?

Any help will greatly appricated.

Full Htaccess;

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^uye-ol/?$ register.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^uye-girisi/?$ login.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^sifremi-unuttum/?$ forget-password.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^yazarlar/?$ writer-list.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^videolar/?$ video-list.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^foto-galeri/?$ gallery-list.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^biyografiler/?$ biography-list.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^yazar/([^/]+)-([^/]+)/([^/]+)-([^/]+)/?$ writer-article.php?link=$1&writerId=$2&articleLink=$3&writerArticleId=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^yazar/([^/]+)-([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ writer-article-list.php?link=$1&writerId=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^foto-galeri/([0-9]+)/?$ gallery-list.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^foto-galeri/([^/]+)-([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ gallery-photo.php?link=$1&i=$2&photo=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^videolar/([^/]+)-([^/]+)/?$ video.php?link=$1&i=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^haber/([^/]+)-([^/]+)/?$ article.php?link=$1&i=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^biyografi/([^/]+)-([^/]+)/?$ biography.php?link=$1&bioId=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ article-list.php?link=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ article-list.php?link=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^videolar/$ video-list.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ article-list.php?link=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ article-list.php?link=$1 [L,QSA]
> RewriteRule ^videolar/$ video-list.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
> ```

You need to change the order of these directives so that the most specific is first. As it stands, the first directive matches the URL `/videolar/1` and so "wins".

However, the last rule you have won't match `/videolar/1` either (it will only match `/videolar/`), so the pattern needs to be modified.

Try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^videolar/([0-9]+)/?$ video-list.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ article-list.php?link=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ article-list.php?link=$1 [L,QSA]
```